# Upload files to S3 with Python (keeping the original folder structure) with correct MIME type

Tags: python, amazon-s3, mime-types, boto3

By default, if `ContentType` isn't set explicitly, `boto3` will upload files to `s3` with `Content-Type: binary/octet-stream`. This is not good, when one using `s3` as static hosting. As of now, [there is PR](https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/1095) for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import boto3
import os
import mimetypes

def upload_files(path):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        region_name='YOUR_ACCOUNT_REGION'
    )
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('YOUR_BUCKET_NAME')

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            file_mime = mimetypes.guess_type(file)[0] or 'binary/octet-stream'
            with open(full_path, 'rb') as data:
                bucket.put_object(Key=full_path[len(path)+1:], Body=data, ContentType=file_mime)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_files('/path/to/your/folder')
```